# Export interfaces instead of structs from golang packages

Tags: go

Below you can find three different ways of calling a method Name() of a customer struct. The result is exactly the same but each one of the three package exports different things:

```
package main

import (
    "customer1"
    "customer2"
    "customer3"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    c1 := customer1.NewCustomer("John")
    fmt.Println(c1.Name())

    c2 := customer2.NewCustomer("John")
    fmt.Println(c2.Name())

    c3 := customer3.NewCustomer("John")
    fmt.Println(c3.Name())
}
```

Output

```
John
John
John
```

customer1.go (Export Customer struct and Name() method)

```
package customer1

type Customer struct {
    name string
}

func NewCustomer(name string) * Customer{
    return &Customer{name: name}
}

func (c *Customer) Name() string {
    return c.name
}
```

customer2.go (Do not export customer struct. Export only Name() method)

```
package customer2

type customer struct {
    name string
}

func NewCustomer(name string) *customer {
    return &customer{name: name}
}

func (c *customer) Name() string {
    return c.name
}
```

customer3.go (Do not export customer struct. Export Customer Interface)

```
package customer3

type Customer interface {
    Name() string
}
type customer struct {
    name string
}

func NewCustomer(name string) Customer {
    return &customer{name: name}
}

func (c *customer) Name() string {
    return c.name
}
```

My question is which approach you would recommend and why? Which is better in terms of extensibility and maintainability? Which one you would use for a large project?

It seems that customer3 approach is officially discouraged (// DO NOT DO IT!!!) as you can read here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces

Comment: This is largely opinion based, but I'll give my opinion anyway: general best practice in Go is "accept interfaces, return structs". And an exported function should never reference an unexported type in its signature. So, I would recommend the first version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interfaces in Go work (and are used) a bit differently that what you'd expect if you come from other languages such as Java.

In Go, the object *implementing* the interface does not need to *explicitly* say it implements it.

That has subtle ramifications, such as the *consumer* of a type being able to decouple from the *implementation* even if the implementing side did not bother (or think about) creating an interface in the first place.

So, the idiomatic way in Go would be to use a variation of your first approach.

You'd define `customer1.go` exactly as you did (so implementation of the type is as simple as possible).

Then **if necessary** you can de-couple in the consumer (your `main` package in this case) by defining an interface there:

```
type Customer interface {
    Name() string
}

func main() {

    var c1 Customer
    c1 := customer1.NewCustomer("John")
    fmt.Println(c1.Name())

}
```

That way, your `main` implementation can work with any type that has a `Name()` method, even if the package implementing the type in the first place did not think about that need.

To achieve extensibility, this is usually also applied for functions you export that receive parameters.

If you are exporting a function like this:

```
func PrintName(customer Customer) {
    fmt.Println(customer.Name())
}
```

Then that function can be invoked with any object that implements `Customer` (any of your implementations would work for example).

Comment: After searching a little bit more based on this answer, I ended up in this great talk by Francesc Campoy Flores called "Understanding Go Interfaces".  Must see for everyone searching to understand Go interfaces better. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4wUrj6pmSI

Comment: very well explained @eugenioy

Comment: @psampaz "This video is private"